# Add a field in node metadata

Tags: 8, nodes, meta-tags

I am trying to make a module that has two parts:

> 1) It calls an API when article is set to published. The API returns a
>   work id.
>
> 2) The workid must be saved to the articles metadata or something
>   similar so that another function uses that id to display specific html
>   in that article.

I am done with the first part. Now I want to know how to save workid in the metadata, is there any option for that in drupal? because I have done this kind of work in joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no such thing as "node metadata", there are just fields.

So the easiest thing to do is to create a field (in the UI for example, you can then also export the configuration into your module), field_work_id or something, and in put in there with `$node->set('field_work_id', $work_id)`.

You can do that in `hook_node_presave()`, but then you might not have an node ID yet for a node that is just being created and is already published. You could also use `hook_node_insert()`/`hook_node_update()`, but then you need resave the node and make sure you don't trigger a loop.

You can also save the work ID in your own table, or you can store the node together with the work ID in a way that allows you to do a lookup with a query.

Comment: what type of field should I select? workid is a really long string

Comment: well, how long is really long? more than 256 characters? Anything less than that is fine as a string/"Text (plain)", if it is even longer then you have to use a string_long/"Text (plain, long)".

Comment: That is resolved now, the problem I am facing is that I am using hook_node_presave and the value of field_workid is not getting saved in the database even when I am trying `$node->save();` I am looking into `node_revision_field_workid` table in the database

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code, I'd suggest creating a new question. You should definitely not call $node->save() in the presave hook

Comment: Thank you sir you have helped a lot. I have not cleared my cache and that was the issue